# How to fix overheating problem after latest updates? Thinkpad x100e running Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, thinkpad, overheating

Noob here. Laptop shuts down and gives thermal shutdown warning only after latest updates Xubuntu 14.04.Tried acpi=off and it seems to help but with other issues. Any ideas on what to try?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with overheating on my laptop. I installed [TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/advanced-power-management-tool-tlp-06.html) and problems were history. Give it a try.